# cron не работает, если в конце crontab нет перевода строки

Tags: linux, cron, crontab

здравствуйте, возникла необходимость использовать крон для своего сайта, до этого я дело с ним не имел, поэтому разбираюсь я в этом довольно плохо

кое как у меня получилось настроить crontab для ежеминутного выполнения get запроса на php файл

вот собственно сам код

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root

# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name  command to be executed

*/1 * * * * root wget -O - -q -t 1 'https://mysite.com/core/common.php?query'
```

но суть проблемы заключается в том, что задача выполняется только если код выглядит так:

```
    SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root

# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name  command to be executed


*/1 * * * * root wget -O - -q -t 1 'https://mysite.com/core/common.php?query'
*  *  *  *  * user-name  command to be executed
```

то есть если помимо первой строки, есть ещё какая то строка (хоть даже пустая), то всё работает, если 1 задача - то нет, и никаких ошибок в логах крона нет, что за бред? спасибо

Comment: пробовали просто пустую строку добавить?

Comment: @KoVadim да, с пустой строкой тоже работает, но если и её нету то нет, идиотизм какой то

Comment: @turik97, никакого идиотизма, а просто кривой редактор, который некорректно сохраняет файл, не добавляя в конец файла символ `lf` (*line feed*, оно же `\n`, шестнадцатиричное значение `0a`)

Answer (score 5):

*TL;DR:* Это не баг, а фича (c)

В руководстве [**crontab**(5)](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/cron/crontab.5.en.html) находим:

> cron requires that each entry in a crontab end in a newline character. If
>   the last entry in  a  crontab  is  missing  a  newline  (ie, terminated by
>   EOF), cron will consider the crontab (at least partially) broken. A warning
>   will be written to syslog.

Что так и означает, что каждая запись в файле crontab должна оканчиваться
символом перевода строки, в т.ч. и последняя. В противном случае cron
игнорирует её и записывает предупреждение в системный журнал. Прочитать его
можно командой `tail /var/log/syslog`.

Стоит заметить, что парсер crontab, используемый в systemd, лишён такой
проблемы.

Comment: Вот тут согласен с оригинальным парсером!

Answer (score 1):

[цитата из википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8#.D0.9F.D0.BE.D1.81.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.B4.D0.BD.D1.8F.D1.8F_.D1.81.D1.82.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.BA.D0.B0):

> Последняя строка
>   Даже в современных изданиях ОС UNIX и Linux отсутствие перевода строки в конце системных конфигурационных файлов приводит к тому, что последняя строка не учитывается, а казалось бы правильно составленный файл не работает, представляясь головоломкой для пользователя, не предупреждённого об этой самобытной особенности.

«нормальные» редакторы всегда вставляют в конец файла символ `lf` (*line feed*, оно же `\n`, шестнадцатиричное значение `0a`).

если вы не уверены в используемом редакторе (в частности, например, если используете для редактирования файла какой-нибудь веб-интерфейс вместо редактора), вставляйте этот символ «руками»: переместите курсор в конец последней строки и нажмите <kbd>enter</kbd>.